# T-SQL to sum total value instead of rejoining table multiple times

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, while-loop, hierarchical

I've looked for an example question like this, I ask for grace if it's been answered (I thought it would have been but have a hard time finding meaningful results with the terms I searched.)

I work at a manufacturing plant where at ever manufacturing operation a part is issued a new serial number.  The database table I have to work with has the serial number recorded in the `Container` field and the previous serial number the part had recorded in the `From_Container` field.

I'm trying to `SUM` the `Extended_Cost` column on parts we've had to re-do operations on.

Here's a sample of data from `tbl_Container`:

```
Container   From_Container  Extended_Cost   Part_Key Operation
10                       9  10               PN_100  60
9                        8  10               PN_100  50
8                        7  10               PN_100  40
7                        6  10               PN_100  30
6                        5  10               PN_100  20
5                        4  10               PN_100  50
4                        3  10               PN_100  40
3                        2  10               PN_100  30
2                        1  10               PN_100  20
1                      100  10               PN_100  10
```

In this example the `SUM` I would expect returned is 40, because operations 20, 30, 40 and 50 were all re-done and cost $10 each.

So far I've been able to do this by rejoining the table to itself 10 times using aliases in the following fashion:

```
      LEFT OUTER JOIN   tbl_Container  AS  FCP_1
                  ON    tbl_Container.From_Container = FCP_1.Container
                  AND   FCP_1.Operation       <= tbl_Container.Operation
                  AND   tbl_Container.Part_Key       = FCP_1.Part_Key
```

And then using `SUM` to add the `Extended_Cost` fields together.  However, I'm violating the DRY principle and there has got to be a better way.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Me

Comment: In other words, you want to perform a hierarchical query. SQL Server has the `hierarchyid` type to represent hierarchies. Or you can use recursive CTEs. There's no reason to use loops.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You may be correct, I am not familiar with hierarchical queries to by asking for a loop I may be asking for the wrong solution.

Comment: What you describe is a well know problem in data processing, the `Bill of Materials` (BOM). Google for `T-SQL BOM` for various solutions. If a material/component is used in only one top-level product/object/whatever, it's essentially a hierarchical query that can be accelerated by a `hierarchyid`. A `hierarchyid` is essentially the path from the current item to the top so it can represent only one hierarchy. If the component is used in multiple products you need either a recursive CTE or another table with the possible paths (tricky)

Comment: Check this possible duplicate [Recursive query for Bill of Materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426812/recursive-query-for-bill-of-materials). Also google for `T-SQL BOM`. This is by no means a simple/solved problem and there are many techniques that can help. The recursion may go too deep, or there may be *cycles* that could result in infinite recursion. You may want to calculate a more complex aggregate (price *with* volume discounts). Graph solutions could also help.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's the same question I found when Googling what you recommended.  Maybe it's a duplicate, I can't tell at first glance but it sure does look like it might be. Should I close or delete this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have tried the code from the link you posted and can not get it to work.  I believe there are similarities but I don't need a counter for how many layers deep this circles through.

Comment: @SDS Why the does the last record of the `from_container` column have a value `100`? I would expect to see that value be `NULL` if it was the first operation. Also, your example join refers to a `part_key` column, but don’t see that in the example data. Do you mind adding that?

Comment: @tarheel changed `Part_No` to `Part_Key`, error on my part.  Also, the `from_container` refers to serial numbers, so the 100 was simply to show the input piece for the first step also has a serial number.  I could have picked any number.  Worth noting is `Container_No` is generated as pieces are produced at our facility.  In my simple example the numbers are one after another, but in reality we have hundreds of parts produced per hour so the numbers are never one right after each other.

Comment: @SDS Understood on the `Container` values not being sequential in the actual data. If the same 10 records of sample data were in the middle of 1000 other records, what could I use to identify where the part creation started? I'd assume that I can find where a part creation ended when there is no record that has a `From_Container` value matching the `Container` value (in this case `Container` value of 10). Do you mind adding sample data for a second part being created? Also, what version of SQL Server are you on? (2008/2012/2014/etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *, I = 0 FROM tbl_Container C ORDER BY Container 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.*, I = I + 1 FROM CTE 
        INNER JOIN tbl_Container T 
            ON CTE.Container = T.From_Container 
            AND CTE.Part_Key = T.Part_Key
)
SELECT Part_Key, SUM(T1.Extended_Cost) Sum_Extended_Cost FROM CTE T1
WHERE 
    EXISTS( SELECT * FROM 
            CTE T2 WHERE 
            T1.Operation = T2.Operation 
            AND T1.I > T2.I ) 
GROUP BY Part_Key
```

Result:

```
Part_Key   Sum_Extended_Cost
---------- -----------------
PN_100     40
```

Comment: I've been slow accepting, trying to test and verify it works before doing so.  Work's been crazy, excited to get it working.  Apologies.