# Recursive SQL Calculation - Recursive Calculation Cannot Be Performed

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, oracle12c

I am working on an Oracle database instance trying to calculate a recursive bill of materials.

My dataset looks like this (there are additional features I don't really need):

```
| Root_Part_No | Sub_Part_No | Sub_Part_Quant |
|--------------|-------------|----------------|
| 132EER       | 122FYY      | 4              |
| 132EER       | 766WWW      | 2              |
| 132EER       | 001EWW      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 472WQA      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 632OIR      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 874RTG      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 888III      | 10             |
| 132EER       | 235CVV      | 5              |
```

I can calculate the first-level BOM well using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Root_Part_No, 
    TRIM(Sub_Part_No) AS "Part", 
    Sub_Part_Qty

FROM 
    TblBOM 

WHERE
    Root_Part_No LIKE "132EE%" 
    AND isEmptyInd != 'Yes'

ORDER BY Root_Part_No, Sub_Part_Qty;
```

However, what I *need* to accomplish is the ability to subsequently calculate the BOM for each of the `Sub_Part_No` that are returned for the item I enter, to ultimately get a table that looks like:

```
| Root_Part_No | Sub_Part_No | Sub_Part_Quant |
|--------------|-------------|----------------|
| 132EER       | 122FYY      | 4              |
| 132EER       | 766WWW      | 2              |
| 132EER       | 001EWW      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 472WQA      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 632OIR      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 874RTG      | 1              |
| 132EER       | 888III      | 10             |
| 132EER       | 235CVV      | 5              |
| 122FYY       | 849ZXA      | 2              |
| 122FYY       | 990JUI      | 10             |
| 122FYY       | 211EEW      | 5              |
| 122FYY       | 211VVV      | 2              |
| 766WWW       | 001EWW      | 10             |
| 766WWW       | 176LKJ      | 2              |
...etc
```

I have tried the following two resources:

- [From IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059242.html) (This is what I am currently following)
- [Recursive Query for Bill Of Materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426812/recursive-query-for-bill-of-materials)
- [`Connect By Prior`](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53139879276132)

I get confused on the `join` section in the second part of the `UNION`.
Any assistance on a path forward is appreciated.

WITH RPL AS (
    SELECT Root_Part_No, TRIM(Sub_Part_No) AS "Part", Sub_Part_Qty
    FROM TblBOM
    WHERE Root_Part_No LIKE "132EE%" AND isEmptyInd != 'Yes'

```
UNION ALL

SELECT Root_Part_No, TRIM(Sub_Part_No) AS "Part", Sub_Part_Qty
FROM TblBOM
LEFT JOIN -- I am confusion

    )

  SELECT DISTINCT -- I am also confusion
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: My driver is 12c, so I'm not sure if that helps. I am unable to tell. I am using SQL Developer to query the instance, if that helps.

Comment: If a part requires x2 subparts, then that subpart requires x3, then... is it still x3 subparts, or x6?

Comment: I would imagine that the "quantity" would refer to the amount needed to build the part currently listed at `Root_Part_No`. Essentially, I think it is a matter of using the one-level query I have against every part number that comes out of the first instance of that query. I know that is recursion, but I can't wrap my mind around how to do it.

Comment: Are you needing this query to be recursive all the way to the base parts that are needed or do you need just that one level like in the examples that you listed? I ask because the parts that are found using queries like in the examples could also then have sub parts.

Comment: You are exactly correct, @drakin8564, I need this all the way to the base until there no longer exists a `sub_part_no` for a given `root_part_no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive query to get what you want is:

```
with
i (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant, lvl) as (
  select 
    root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant, 1
  from tblbom where root_part_no like '132EE%' and isemptyind <> 'Yes'
  union all -- anchor member above; recursive member below
  select
    p.root_part_no, p.sub_part_no, p.sub_part_quant, i.lvl + 1
  from i
  join tblbom p on p.root_part_no = i.sub_part_no
)
select * 
from i
order by lvl, root_part_no, sub_part_no
```

Pay attention to the `UNION ALL` clause. It separates the **anchor query** -- run only once -- from the **recursive query** that is run multiple times for every **new row** that results from it, until it produces no new rows anymore. This way this query can walk multiple levels, not just 2 of them.

**Edit**:

I tested the query above with the following (made up) data, and I added the `LVL` column to show the recursive level:

```
create table tblbom (
  root_part_no varchar2(10),
  sub_part_no varchar2(10),
  sub_part_quant number(6),
  isemptyind varchar2(10) default 'No'
);

insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('132EER', '122FYY', 1);
insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('132EER', '766WWW', 2);
insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('122FYY', '849ZXA', 3);
insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('766WWW', '111111', 4);
insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('849ZXA', null, 5);
insert into tblbom (root_part_no, sub_part_no, sub_part_quant) values ('111111', null, 6);
```

The Result (including level) is:

```
ROOT_PART_NO  SUB_PART_NO  SUB_PART_QUANT  LVL
------------  -----------  --------------  ---
132EER        122FYY       1               1  
132EER        766WWW       2               1  
122FYY        849ZXA       3               2  
766WWW        111111       4               2  
111111        <null>       6               3  
849ZXA        <null>       5               3
```

Comment: Hey @TheImpaler, thanks a lot for your answer. So, maybe I didn't word my question the right way. This definitely works, but it seems to only pull the FIRST level. Meaning, I just tried running it and it is pulling all of the FIRST level materials, similar to mine, but it is not pulling the BOM for those resulting part numbers. So something is off :(

Comment: I believe you could get it to pull all of the following levels by using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. `UNION ALL` removed duplicates so you would see only the first one. This could also cause issues with the recursion so be ready to kill the query if it starts running too long.

Comment: Removal of the `UNION ALL` syntax resulted in an `ORA-32040: recursive WITH clause must use a UNION ALL operation`

Comment: Then you'll need to tweak the join condition `join tblbom p on p.root_part_no = i.sub_part_no`. This condition selects subparts `p` based on previously selected items `i`.

Comment: @drakin8564 You cannot remove `UNION ALL`. Oracle requires them to process recursive queries.

Comment: What does it need to be tweaked, to? I have that currently, and it is pulling all of the first-level items great, but it is not pulling the subsequent subcomponents of the first_level of subcomponents

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but, the `Root_Part_No` never changes in this implementation.

Comment: I created some data locally using three levels, and it works as expected (results above). If you provide a dbfiddle I can help you with your specific case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191748/discussion-between-jerry-m-and-the-impaler).

Comment: This wasn't working because of a `TRIM` error on my part. You were right. Thank you so much this is phenomenal.